# Primeng editor converting non http urls to about:blank

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Primeng editor converts non http urls to about:blank.

I want it to except all different urls or any option to whitelist few urls?
If there is any way to handle in text change or by using custom link in editor's toolbar. Please let me know.

Comment: You tagged this question with datatable, so you want to not render links in the datatable? or render them, even if they are empty? How do you pass these links ot the datatable?

Comment: Removed the tag to avoid confusion, Question is related to primeng editor.